# Is everything needed to go through the custom renderer

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I got a Xamarin.Forms app, I got a xaml page the using a map that has some buttons (street, hybrid, satellite), I got an click event on each of those buttons that run this code:

```
MyMap.MapType = MapType.Hybrid;
```

I'm using a custom map in my Xamarin.Android proj that renders the map. But when I click on any of the buttons the click event is triggered and the code runs but it doesn't change the MapType. Do I need to make the changes in the custom render class instead of in the code behind of the xaml page?

Comment: for what control you want to use your renderer and for what you don't? Are you using it on button, on map? Can you clarify the question?

Comment: Im using a custom render for the map in my android proj. I did edit the post.

Comment: When I change my map type it changes, I didn't have to do anything in renderer